# Correct way to define many to many relationship with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5, many-to-many

I have two models:

**BlogPost model:**

```
class BlogPost extends Model {

    protected $table = 'blog_posts';

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'BlogCategory', 'blog_category_post', 'post_id', 'category_id' );
    }

}
```

**and BlogCategory model:**

```
class BlogCategory extends Model {

    protected $table = 'blog_categories';


    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany( 'BlogPost', 'blog_category_post', 'category_id', 'post_id' );
    }

}
```

Is it the correct way of using the 3rd and 4th parameters in belongsToMany() for the 2 models ?

It seems to be working because the pivot table is filled when attach() method is called:

```
if ( is_array( $request->get('categories') ) && count( $request->get('categories') ) ) {
            $post->categories()->attach( $request->get('categories') );
        }
```

but fails when using detach() with this error:

**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::detach()**

```
foreach ( $post->categories as $category ) {
            $post->categories->detach( $category->id );
            echo "<br />" . $category->id;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `$post->categories()->detach( $category->id );`? `$post->categories` returns a collection, while `$post->categories()` returns a relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have call `detach` on the relation instance, not the collection.

```php
foreach ($post->categories as $category) {
    $post->categories()->detach($category->id);
    //               ^^
}
```

---

BTW, it seems you want to remove all categories. You can achieve that by simply not passing anything to the `detach` method:

```php
$post->categories()->detach();
```

Much more efficient.

Comment: Also, if the OP is pruning all and then inserting relations, perhaps the 'sync()' method will be more succinct. Simply pass an array of foreign keys and Eloquent will synchronise the pivot table by doing the pruning and inserting.